# Struct existence in functions/methods

Tags: c++

Say

```
a_function(mystruct::create().execute());
```

`create()` creates an instance of struct as `mystruct s()`
then the method `execute()` returns something.

does the struct continue to exist for the entire time the function is executed or is it released?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to know? If your code depends on this, it is likely not very good.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Nonsense. It's often very important to know the lifetime of your objects, especially when they're temporaries. If you don't, you'll end up dynamically allocating everything with a heavy hand and leaving memory leaks everywhere. This is a good question.

Comment: @Tomalak: The function does not take the temporary as parameter, but the return value of a function invoked on that temporary. If this return value is in some way bound to the lifetime of the temporary (which indicated by the OPs question), then there might be a problem with the design, and I would check twice if I actually need this.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: The return value of `mystruct::create().execute()` is a temporary too.

Comment: @Tomalak: It is, but why is the OP worried about the lifetime of the struct, instead of the lifetime of the returned value?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Without knowing the contents of the functions, who can know? I am not psychic. A good example of this sort of concern might be: `use_buffer(get_buffer_in(make_temporary_vector()));` where "buffer" refers to `std::vector`'s internal array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temporary `struct` object exists until the full expression is over. That means until `a_function` has been returned from.

See 12.2 in C++03.

Answer (score 3):

It exists until the function returns.

Answer (score 2):

You can rest assured that a temporary object will exist as long as the full expression in which it is created hasn't been evaluated, which means your struct will "exist" until the `a_function` has returned.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are some special conditions for extending the lifetime, any temporaries created in an expression will be destroyed at the end of the full expression. Here this is at the semi-colon.

You are even assured that multiple temporary objects will be destroyed in the reverse order of their creation, as always.